# How to create a hand shake effect in png?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a png in which I want the hands to shake. I am providing the link to the image:

[image]

Please prefer using CSS, JS, HTML and jquery to do so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YmwS.png

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pr1umzowf7m2c4l/logo.png?dl=0

Comment: Above link is for the png file thanks!

Comment: Thx for the tumult solution how would i animate the image to shake hands?

Answer (score 1):

css is enough to achieve shake effect:

```
.handshake:hover {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d( 0, -1px, 0);
  }

  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 2px, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 4px, 0);
  }
}
```

but to make it realistic you will need to animate the elements in the image itself. You could use program like Adobe Animate (former Flash) to export animated gif (which will btw. look far uglier and take much more space then the flash's primary export format swf).

Comment: So whats the best to animate the elements can you take the png file animate it please!

Comment: Kindly suggest me more ways please i need to this!

Comment: Hey guys kindly provide solutions please i need to solve this as soon as possible!

Comment: Thx for the tumult solution how would i animate the image to shake hands?

Comment: hey, sorry, I was AFK... maybe this question should be transferred in graphic design because it is not related to programming any more. Anyway... have you tried to apply the code above to the image? What do you think about the animation? If you are able to separate the image in 2 (or 4) layers you could left the background static and apply the motion only on hands. (or maybe even on upper and lower arm)